# Routing desk phone through computer

Tags: telephony, pbx

Is there a device into which I could plug a line from the telephone socket in the wall, and then a second port that I can connect to my desk phone?

Then, using software, I could place calls, see caller ID etc from my computer?

Comment: There are TONS of VoIP phone systems that will do this (if you replace 'telephone socket' with 'ethernet').

Comment: Is it just me, or does seeing the images below "relive the excitement" of connecting to the internet with the noise of these modems? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is, a **PCI fax modem**.

[image]

or for laptops, a **USB fax modem**

[image]

Then any good old "Caller ID" software will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any for Linux?

Comment: @Gausie - I am sure they exist.

Comment: @Gausie - the classic is `mgetty`.